# Mover un div de manera continua e infinita con javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy tratando que al presionar el botón que dice "Iniciar", el cuadrado se empiece a mover de izquierda a derecha hasta cierto punto límite, una vez alcanzado ese límite, el cuadrado debe devolverse a su posición inicial y de ahí volver a ejecutarse la función de manera infinita, para que el cuadrado se mueva siempre de izquierda a derecha y viceversa.

Hasta el momento solo he podido hacer que se mueva hacia la derecha, de ahí no se cómo devolverlo y reiniciar la función, quise usar una especie de bandera con la posición `left`, pero al hacerlo el cuadrado ya ni se movía.

Éste es el código que llevo hasta el momento:

```js
function mover() {
  document.getElementById('cuadrado').style.left = "400px";
}
```

```css
.cuadrado {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<p><button type="button" id="btnIniciar" onclick="mover()">Iniciar</button></p>
<div class="cuadrado" id="cuadrado"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No necesitas javascript para manipular directamente la posición de tu cuadrado.

La clave está en usar CSS animations (checa esta [guia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations) y esta [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations)) y usar solo javascript para cambiar la 'clase' del cuadrado cuando se hace click en el botón.

Usa este código:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>Prueba1</title>
    
    <style>
      .cuadrado
      {
         width: 100px;
         height: 100px;
         background: blue;
         position: absolute;
      }
      .cuadrado.moviendo{
        animation-duration: 1s;
        animation-name: moviendo;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        animation-direction: alternate;
        animation-timing-function: linear;
      }
      @keyframes moviendo {
        from {
          left: 0;
        }
        to {
          left: 400px;
        }
      }
    </style>
    
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <p><button type="button" id="btnIniciar" onclick="mover()" >Iniciar</button></p>
    <div class="cuadrado" id="cuadrado"></div>
    
    <script>
      function mover()
      {
        document.getElementById('cuadrado').classList.add('moviendo');
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hay muchas opciones con las que puedes jugar, como la suavidad en el desplazamiento (`animation-timing-function`).

Espero te sirva la respuesta y cualquier duda, preguntame.